# How do I attach variables to the view context in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

**Controller**

```
class PageController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function editAction()
    {
        $this->view->attach('name' => 'crazor');

        echo $this->view->render('account/info.phtml');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<p>Hello, <?php echo $this->name; ?></p>
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I need to send variable data to the View which will then render it. In this case, it's the persons `name`.

Is this possible in Zend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, it is.
try

```
$this->view->__set('myvarname', 'myvarvalue');
```

or just

```
$this->view->myvarname = 'myvarvalue';
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you where looking for `assign`

```
$this->view->assign('name', 'crazor');
```

I prefer the assign method because it lets me nicely add multiple variables to the view

```
$this->view->assign('firstname', 'Peter')
           ->assign('lastname', 'Miller');
```